# Python ImportError when module is in sys.path

Tags: python, command-line, python-import, importerror

I'm working with Python in the command line and want to import the module 'twitter'. twitter is in this directory: `C:\Users\U908153\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\Lib\site-packages`

`sys.path` tells me that the above directory is in sys.path.

Still, when I write `import twitter`, I get `ImportError: No module named twitter`.

What is going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you installed twitter module?

Comment: Yes, I did, it is in the C:\Users... directory

Comment: is the file your are running called `twitter.py`?

Comment: I'm not running a file, right, because I am working in the command line? But this is my entry: python download_tweets_api.py --dist=tweeti-a.dist.tsv --output=downloaded.tsv

Comment: yep. right. that is just one of the most frequent import problems... and the interpreter you were printing `sys.path` from is the same as the one your run your twitter program with?

Comment: Ah, no, it isn't the same. And now you mention it, if I print sys.path from the command line, it actually gives me a different list of directories not containing the twitter one...

Comment: But there is another issue now. It seems I can only run "python download_tweets_api.py --dist=tweeti-a.dist.tsv --output=downloaded.tsv" from the command line itself (not having opened the Python program beforehand). But if I'm not working from Python, then how can I reset the sys.path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things that commonly result in this error:

1. Module is not in PYTHONPATH. Since you have checked this with `sys.path`, I will assume that it is there already. However, for future reference, you can manually add it to your `profile` or `bashrc` file in the home directory.
2. It may be that the module that you are using doesn't have a `__init__.py` file or the module path in PYTHONPATH doesn't point to the uppermost directory with `__init__.py`. You can fix this by adding a blank `__init__.py` file where necessary or editing the module path.
3. Another possibility is that the python interpreter that you used `sys.path` is not the same python in which the module was installed. Commonly, this is due to two different versions of python installed on the same machine. Make sure that your module is installed for the correct python interpreter or switch into the correct (usually not default) python using `source activate`.

Hope this helps!